# setTooltipText for TreeItem not defined

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Greetings fellow Stackoverflownians!

I am building an Eclipse RCP application, and have come across an issue:

I want to set a tooltip text on a [TreeItem](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TreeItem.html), but this class does not inherit [Control](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html), which is the class that has the `setTooltipText`

**EDIT**: It seems that jface is supposed to take care of this seamlessly, through a `LabelProvider`.
I am using a `ColumnLabelProvider` with `getToolTipText` method on each column of a complex `TreeViewer`, but it isn't working. I wonder why...

Comment: Are you using `TreeViewer` or just `Tree`?

Comment: the jface TreeViewer, unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `TreeViewer` use

```
ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor(viewer);
```

Use a label provider derived for `CellLabelProvider` or one of it subclasses and override `getToolTipText` (there are also several other methods to control the font, time out and the like).

Comment: This is 100% necessary for TreeViewers, otherwise it doesn't work? Hmm.

Comment: Okay. I realized that the two answers need to be combined, but this was the essential step. Thanks again Greg!

Comment: As a further comment, I would like to say that sometimes, the Eclipse API is awful :(

Answer (score 4):

The probleme here is that you use the SWT-Tree.
You should use a TreeViewer (JFace) which wraps the tree and gives you more sophisticated options.
Inside the label provider of the TreeViewer, you can define your tooltips.

Learn more about viewers [here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2Fpackage-summary.html) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFace/article.html#jfaceviewer)

An code example (tool tip) is [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet015CustomTooltipsForTree.java)

I strongly recommend you to use the viewers!

Comment: actually am using them, and will check this out, then accept it. Appreciation++

Comment: Using your snippet was useful, but without the enableFor from greg's answer it was not working on my example. Had to change the accepted answer, but frankly, I would combine the two...